# Is Hive on Spark supported by MapR cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, mapr

I would like to execute hive queries on spark. Currently we are using mapreduce as execution engine. please do let me know is spark support to execute hive queries on MapR cluster?.

earlier i executed hive queries on spark engine with Cloudera. But not sure about MapR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shark , check the below link.
https://www.mapr.com/products/product-overview/shark

You can call hive queries from Spark-SQL which is much faster.
Please follow below spark 2.0 documentation ,

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: I think Spark summit announced shark development is ended and their focus is on spark SQL. So i want to use spark SQL not shark. Do you have any idea/experience about hive on spark on mapr cluster.